# How Do I create a countdown timer with minutes and seconds in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, countdowntimer, seconds, minute

I can't find a single tutorial that does countdown timer with minutes and seconds. There's one or two but they are kind of bad.

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var focusSession: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var breakSession: UILabel!

    var prodSeconds = String() // This value is set in a different view controller
    lazy var intProdSeconds = Int(prodSeconds)
    var timer = Timer()
    var isTimerRunning = false  // Make sure only one timer is running at a time

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if isTimerRunning == false {
            runProdTimer()
        }

        //focusSession.text = String(prodMinutes) + ":" + String(prodSeconds) // Ignore this for now stack overflow ppl
    }

    func runProdTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(HomeViewController.updateProdTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isTimerRunning = true
    }

    @objc func updateProdTimer() {
        if intProdSeconds! < 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
            focusSession.text = "00:00"
        }
        else {
            intProdSeconds! -= 1
            focusSession.text = prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval(prodSeconds)!)
        }
    }

    func prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let prodMinutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let prodSeconds = Int(time) % 60

        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", prodMinutes, prodSeconds)
    }
}
```

The user inputs their time amount and it is stored in the `prodSeconds` variable which is then converted to an `Int` below it with the `lazy` variable.

However, the timer **still doesn't countdown** when I run the app.
This is supposedly just a timer for seconds which I was following from a different tutorial. But all that happens is that the label that displays the timer simply displays the number inputted by the user in the format of `00:prodSeconds` and doesn't actually countdown.

P.S. Don't worry about implementing a start/stop button for now. In my case, the timer is supposed to start when the view loads.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your `prodTimeString` function works just fine. Pass in `90` and you get `01:30`.

Comment: You might want to avoid simply subtracting 1 every second; `Timer` is not very accuracte. I would suggest you calculate the `Date` that corresponds to your end time and then use `timeIntervalSinceNow` to calculate the remaining time. Also, run your timer at less than a second, say 0.5s, in order to avoid jitter in your countdown

Comment: @rmaddy Ok, I see that now...but the thing is, the user will be inputting minutes not seconds...right now, whatever input that goes in is read as seconds not minutes...how would I have it so that the minutes inputted by the user is taken in as minutes and then converted to seconds?

Comment: Multiply by 60.

Comment: @rmaddy Never mind I got it lol...thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you count down from

```
intProdSeconds! -= 1
```

and pass `prodSeconds` to this

```
focusSession.text = prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval(prodSeconds)!)
```

so make sure to deal only with `intProdSeconds`